# python parse html from url with AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, html, csv, parsing

I want to parse html table from ur to csv but I get error in code: page.find_all('tr'):

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'find_all'

```
import urllib
import os
import csv

cwd = os.getcwd()
myFolder=cwd+"\In"
url="http://biznes.pap.pl/pl/reports/espi/all,0,0,0,1"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

with open('listing.csv', 'w') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
    for tr in page.find_all('tr'):
     tds = tr.find_all('td')
     row = [str(elem.text.encode('utf-8'))[1:] for elem in tds[:12]]
     writer.writerow(row)

print("Creating listing.csv file... ") 
print("Done... ")
```

I think its something other in this urls.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the API usage, it looks like you meant to initialize the `BeautifulSoup` object:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# ...

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

with open('listing.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [str(elem.text.encode('utf-8'))[1:] for elem in tds[:12]]

        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I got not what i want because file include: "'21:00','\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t11/2017\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t','\n\nTermo2Power "

Comment: @JakubMedon that's now a different problem which may be solved by stripping the cell values: `row = [str(elem.get_text(strip=True).encode('utf-8'))[1:] for elem in tds[:12]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need a parser, ie `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Then after

```
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

comes

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
```

and

```
with open('listing.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    # --------^^^^---------------
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I got error "FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?"

Comment: Yup: `pip install bs4 html5lib` on the console.

Comment: @JakubMedon: Then change it to `soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")` and install `lxml` via `pip install lxml`.